# Java/Kotlin - convert Set to Map<Long, Set<Long>>

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

I have Set of Long values

```
Set<Long> ids = {1,2,3,4}
```

What I'd like to achieve is

```
Set<Map<Long, Set<Long>>
```

and from this Set of ids I need to have Set with 4 elements like:

```
Set: {
Map -> key: 1, values: 2,3,4
Map -> key: 2, values: 1,3,4
Map -> key: 3, values: 1,2,4
Map -> key: 4, values: 1,2,3
}
```

How can i get it by `stream` or maybe kotlin's `groupBy` ?

Was anyone going to have a map like this? (Solution without a `for` or `while` loop)

Comment: Is this a learning task or what is the reason not to use a loop directly? Using a stream you _could_ create a map with the elements being the keys and the values being copies of the original set with the key removed.

Comment: Besides that, what is the purpose of having a set of maps which only have one key? Do you mean a map's entry set, i.e. `Set<Map.Entry<Long,Set<Long>>`? If not, why not directly use a single map?

Comment: Tkanhs for answears ;) The task requires such a solution from me. Need Set <Map>.

Comment: What could the solution look like with Set<Map.Entry<Long,Set<Long>>?

Comment: If you want to get an entry set just create the map and call `entrySet()` on it. In Java the map could be created using `Collectors.toMap(e->e, e->{ /*create copy of original set, remove e and return the set*/ })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Opinions on kotlin `groupBy`

Notice that `groupBy` can just split the original set into severial sets without intersection. So it's impossible to construct the mentioned map directly with `groupBy` function.

The solution below take advantage of `groupBy` when getting `result`, but `result2` is much more clear to read and meets intuition:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val set = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

    val result = set
        .groupBy { it }
        .mapValues { (_, values) -> set.filter { it !in values } }

    println(result) // {1=[2, 3, 4], 2=[1, 3, 4], 3=[1, 2, 4], 4=[1, 2, 3]}


    val result2 = HashMap<Int, List<Int>>().apply {
        set.forEach { this[it] = (set - it).toList() }
    }
    println(result2) // {1=[2, 3, 4], 2=[1, 3, 4], 3=[1, 2, 4], 4=[1, 2, 3]}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use use `map` method to transform every element to `Map` then collect it to `set`

```
var set = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
var map = set.map { v -> mapOf(v to set.filter { it != v }.toSet()) }
    .toSet()
```

However I don't believe it's much better than simple `foreach` loop due to performance or readability

Comment: set.toMutableSet() is not necessary, set.toSet() will do.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a possible solution with a for loop:

```
val ids: Set<Long> = setOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

var result: MutableSet<Map<Long, Set<Long>>> = mutableSetOf()

for (id in ids) {
  result.add(mapOf(id to ids.filter { it != id }.toSet()))
}

println(result)
```